# Link leads to localhost/wordpress instead of website.site/wordpress

Tags: html

I have handwritten HTML page that is my basic experiment while studying.
I also have a wordpress page, which resides in the website directory in a folder named wordpress.

The current link is

```
<a href="http://www.simontuomi.site/wordpress">
```

Which resides on the start page of my site, simontuomi.site.
But the link leads to localhost/wordpress/, instead of http://simontuomi.site/wordpress/.

I have tried writing only /wordpress as a href link too, but it doesn't work.
Even writing http://simontuomi.site/wordpress/ by hand in the browser leads to localhost/wordpress on my phone, which obviously won't work since it's hosted on my desktop PC.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was Wordpress itself that was wrongly configured in the Settings -> General menu, to make the site URL localhost/wordpress.